# Add parallel lists of keys and values to a hash table in Racket?

Tags: hashtable, racket

I have a list of keys and a list of values that I want to add to a hash table. The best I've got so far is:

```
(apply hash-set*! table (flatten (map list keys values)))
```

But that makes a lot of nested lists only to flatten them.

Is there a simple way to do this without making the nested lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest `'for'` loop can be used here:

```
(for ([k keys]
      [v vals])
  (hash-set! table k v))
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless your lists are tens of thousands long it really doesn't matter but in the name of laziness here is what I would have done:

```scm
(require srfi/26) ; cut

(for-each (cut hash-set! table <> <>) keys vals)
```

Same without [SRFI-26](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-26/srfi-26.html):

```scm
(for-each (λ (k v) (hash-set! table k v)) keys vals)
```

Comment: Yes, it's not an efficiency thing. It's more of an elegance thing, and wondering if there's an idiomatic way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would write it like this:

```
#lang racket

(define keys '(a b c))
(define values '(1 2 3))
(define table (hash 'p 34 'c 9))

(for/fold ([ht table])
          ([k (in-list keys)]
           [v (in-list values)])
  (hash-set ht k v))
```

... no extra consing required.